# Update to a specific version of Safari for iPadOS

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I am using the iPad's Safari (browser) for development testing.

I need a specific version of safari that is 13.1.

The current version is lower than that. If I update safari from the app store it will update to the latest release version (~14).

How can I install a specific version of Safari on the iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of Safari browser is tied to the version of iPadOS running on your iPad. It's not possible to pick and install a specific version of Safari which is lower than the current latest version of iPadOS.

If you wish to use a specific version for development and testing, you can install Xcode on your Mac, which would give you access to iOS/iPadOS simulators running on macOS.

Thereafter you can pick and download a specific older version of iPadOS (such as iPadOS 13.1).

The only con is that instead of Safari running on a real iPad device, you'd be testing on a software simulator of Safari for iPad running atop a desktop/laptop computer.